# get row no through mysql query

Tags: mysql

How to get the row no through mysql query for each row? 
(i want to display sno)
Please help me sir

Comment: If you really want an answer to this question, post table def, and state your question much, much clearer (for instance, waht is the "sno" you want to display?)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking to see if you can get the row number for each row through MySQL query right? here's one:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS ‘rownum’, t.* FROM `table` AS t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) `r`
```

Answer (score 2):

It's awesome for paging results in search , queries and bla bla bla like this :

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS ‘row’, t.* FROM `table` AS t, (SELECT @row:=0) `r`) as Tx
where `row` > 10 limit 10
```